# How to install new faucet with old water shutoff valve

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I'm installing a new faucet and noticed that the instructions call for the faucet water line to be bolted directly onto the shutoff valve. The problem is, my shutoff valves have built-in lines which don't unbolt.

What is the best thing for me to do? Should I install new shutoff valves that have bolt-on connections or somehow connect the existing water line to the faucet's water line?

(shutoff valve at top, faucet line at bottom)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All faucets now use standardized connectors for the water supply.  So yes, you should replace that water shut off valve with a standardized one - might as well do it now and save the frustration.

Comment: Those are some pretty unusual shutoffs. Anyway, it looks like they are compression fittings and they should just unscrew. Hopefully you can shutoff the main water supply.